# Replace words in a textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to replace certain words by **** in my TEXTAREA but this script does not work. Thank you for your help

```
<TEXTAREA style="color:black;" name="Body" id="Body" value="" rows="6" cols="60" maxlength="160"></TEXTAREA><br/>
<script>
var input = document.getElementById('Body')[0],
    output = document.getElementById('Body')[0],
    badwords = /\b(test|test2|test3)\b/g;

input.onkeyup = function () {
    output.innerHTML = this.value.replace(badwords, function (fullmatch, badword) {
        return '<sub>' + new Array(badword.length + 1).join('*') + '</sub>';
    });
};

input.onkeyup();
input.focus();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a working solution, with explanations in the comments:

```js
//remove [0].  getElementById returns an element, not a collection:
var input = document.getElementById('Body'),
    output = document.getElementById('Body'),
    badwords = /\b(test1|test2|test3)\b/g;

//addEventListener is the best way to add listeners:
input.addEventListener('keyup', function() {  

//Change innerHTML to value here:
  output.value = this.value.replace(badwords, function (fullmatch, badword) { 

//Remove '<sub>...</sub>'.  Textareas support text content only.
    return new Array(badword.length + 1).join('*');  
  });
});

input.focus();
```

```html
<TEXTAREA style="color:black;" name="Body" id="Body" value="" rows="6" cols="60" maxlength="160"></TEXTAREA><br/>
```